Azure B2C / WPF - Handling a failed MFA verification flow
I have the following client code to fetch a token from Azure B2C endpoint:
public static async Task<AuthenticationResult> AcquireTokenAsync(this IPublicClientApplication publicClientApp)
{
   try
   {
      var accounts = await publicClientApp.GetAccountsAsync();

      return await Task.Run(() =>
                publicClientApp
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(apiScopes)
                    .WithAccount(accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
                    .ExecuteAsync());
   }
   catch (MsalClientException ex)
   {
       if (ex.ErrorCode.Equals("authentication_canceled"))
       {
           log.Info("Authentication was cancelled");
       }

       log.Error("Error in login sequence", ex);
       throw;
   }
}

Where publicClientApp is created as such:
app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(ClientId)
                        .WithB2CAuthority(Authority)
                        .Build();

I would like to be able to distinguish different "error code" situations, taking into account MFA. So far I have been able to capture when user cancels/closes the authentication window - which throws MsalClientException with an error code authentication_canceled.
Next I would like to capture the failed MFA verification, and by debugging the code I can see that after failing the verification enough times, the AcquireTokenInteractive throws:
Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: 
The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
 

With an error code: authentication_ui_failed
Stack trace:
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.net45.WebUI.<AcquireAuthorizationAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<AcquireAuthorizationAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.InteractiveRequest.<ExecuteAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<RunAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.PublicClientExecutor.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at MyProject.AzureB2CIntegration.PublicClientApplicationExtensions.<AcquireTokenAsync>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\My\Common\AzureB2CIntegration\PublicClientApplicationExtensions.cs:line 23

However, when inspecting the traffic on Fiddler, I get a more sensible error response from B2C:
status=500 Internal Server Error
error=server_error
error_description=AADB2C90151: User has exceeded the maximum number for retries for multi-factor authentication.

Question - is there a way to get a more detailed error information (like the one from Fiddler) from an exception that is thrown by AcquireTokenInteractive in such case?

the field error_description that Fiddler shows should be inspectable soemwhere in the response object in C#

Try logging ex.ErrorCode and ex.ErrorText before your throw statement. These values are populated from query parameters extracted from the redirect uri after authentication fails. So you could also see the values in Fiddler.

And check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1125805/azure-b2c-mfa-query

@Pac0 That's the thing - the exception does not contain any traces of AADB2C90151, making me wonder whether the exception I am getting is indeed the right one, ie. perhaps something is not being handled at the right place? However I am drawing a blank..

@ArchitectJamie I can log/print the value of ex.ErrorCode, which is  "authentication_ui_failed". However I do not know where to find ex.ErrorText, could you help me out?

@RollerMobster I used this codesnip1, codesnip2 and MFA is promoted, user signed in successfully and access token generated successfully

@Rukmini Thanks for your suggestions. I have tried to add .WithRedirectUri("http://localhost") to the PublicClientApplicationBuilder, and now I am getting the same MsalClientException with the same error code "authentication_ui_failed" immediately, without having to enter the verification code.
Could this mean theres a problem with the app registration configuration in Azure, specifically with the Redirect uri?

Did you configure redirect URL under mobile and desktop platform as http://localhost?

And did you enable MFA In user flow?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Sorry, I meant to say ex.Message, not ErrorText. These are the members of ex that you can log to see if you have a more detailed error message: ErrorCode, Message, StatusCode, CorrelationId, Claims, ResponseBody, InnerException, StackTrace.

@RollerMobstert posting as solution, let me know if anything need to add

Thank you all for great suggestions - I finally got it working. Turns out behind the scenes I was using a Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.1.0 (due to it being wrapped around by another nuget, dohh). Once that got replaced with the most recent one, things started clicking as I expected.

I created an Azure AD B2C application and added redirect URL like below:

Enabled mobile and desktop flows:

Enable MFA in the user flow:

When I ran the WPF application, I got the sign in screen like below:

The user redirected to MFA prompt:

After sign-in the tokens are generated and you can call the API using the token:

You can find the complete project in my Gitrepo Rukmini3394/WPFApp (github.com)
Reference:
Azure B2C MFA Query - Microsoft Q&A by Givary-MSFT
